# SQL functions in GET DIAGNOSTICS stack PG_CONTEXT

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I use PostgreSQL 9.6.
Upgrade might be an option if this is solved in newer versions.

Here's a slightly modified example from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK.
Changes:

- functions are in schema x, not public
- `outer_func` is SQL, not plpgsql
- `outer_func` has `SELECT 1`

```
CREATE SCHEMA x;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.inner_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  stack text;
BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS stack = PG_CONTEXT;
  RAISE NOTICE E'\n--- Call Stack ---\n%', stack;
  RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.outer_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
  SELECT 1;  
  SELECT x.inner_func();
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT x.outer_func()
```

Output:

```
--- Call Stack ---
PL/pgSQL function x.inner_func() line 5 at GET DIAGNOSTICS
SQL function "outer_func" statement 2
 outer_func 
------------
          1
(1 row)
```

**Main question**: how do find schema of `outer_func`? Plpgsql functions are prefixed with schema name (`x.inner_func()`), SQL functions are without it.

(Why do I need it: I want to perform something whenever there's a function in certain schema in the stack, those functions might be both in SQL/plpgsql)

**Bonus question**: when i remove `SELECT 1` then `outer_function` entirely disappears from the stack:

```
--- Call Stack ---
PL/pgSQL function x.inner_func() line 5 at GET DIAGNOSTICS
 outer_func 
------------
          1
(1 row)
```

I guess single-statement SQL functions are somehow compressed, am I correct? Is there any way to avoid it (other than adding additional redundant statement)?

Comment: If you remove the `SELECT 1` from your SQL function, it's highly likely that it gets [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), thus there is no function call to begin with. For non-inlined SQL functions, there is no "call stack" as that refers to PL/pgSQL, not to a "statement"

Comment: OK, so I can get function name (`SQL function "outer_func"`), but there's no way of finding its schema if its not plpgsql?

Comment: @jbet - this depends on language implementation - and SQL language doesn't return this information. This inconsistency is +/- bug and can be fixed, but it doesn't help you with Postgres 9.6. More this information is not stable - if schema is inside search_path, then you cannot to read schema for plpgsql functions too.